# Html & CSS media not work with me

Tags: html, css

```css
#mobile { display: inline;}

#desktop { display: none;}

header, main, nav, footer, figure, figcaption, aside, section, article {display: block;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 64em){
    body {background-color: #ffffff;}
    wraper {width: 0;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: none;}
    main {margin-left: 0;}
    nav {float: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
        padding: 0.5em;}
    li {display: inline;
        padding-top: 0.25em;
    padding-bottom: 0.25em;
    padding-left: 0.75em;
    padding-right: 0.75em;}
    homehero, yurthero, trailhero {margin-left: 0;
    height: 200px;}
    footer {margin-left: 0;}
        
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) {
    header {padding-top: 1em;}
    main {padding-top: 0.1em;
    padding-bottom: 0.1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    font-size: 90%;}
    h1 {font-size: 1.5em;}
    nav {padding: 0;}
    li {display: block;
        margin: 0;
        border-bottom: 2px #330000;}
    a {display: block;}
    homehero, yurthero, trailhero {background-image: none;
    height: 0;}
    mobile {display: inline;}
    disktop {display: none;}
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Pacific Trails Resort</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pacific.css">
<link rel="stylesheet"  media= "screen and (max-width: 37.5em)" href="pacific.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"  media= "screen and (max-width: 64em)" href="pacific.css"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale to 1.0" >




</head>
```

I try to configure styles for mobile and tablet by using media
But it not work with me
what is solution for that?

Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvVZL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpND9.jpg)

This what I need
but I get this

Comment: The beauty of media queries is that you don't need to add extra CSS `<link>`s. One CSS link is sufficient, the rest are redundant. Get rid of them!

Comment: Are these all classes? `homehero, yurthero, trailhero {}` if so, and a `.` before them.

Answer (score 1):

instead

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale to 1.0" >
```

try it

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```